# How to publicly access virtual windows server 2008 R2 on Ubuntu 13.10 using VMware player 6.0?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, vmware-player

I am using Ubuntu 13.10 and VMware player 6.0 for virtual windows server 2008 R2. I have to check something in SharePoint 2010. Both host and guest can access internet. Now I want to access SharePoint by other machine in internet. Means guest virtual windows server 2008 R2 server must be visible publicly in internet. Please advise me how can do it?

P.S: I am using ADSL internet and have full control to configure it. My http server in Ubuntu is already publicly accessible.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what I did for running VirtualBox on Ubuntu Server 13.04 to host a windows virtual machine.  I am sure this will be similar to your scenario

First, make sure you are using the PCNet Ethernet for the virtual machine.

Next modify your networking:

`nano /etc/network/interfaces`

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto br0
iface br0 inet static
address 192.168.2.98 #<- Change this to the internal IP address of your Ubuntu box
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 192.168.2.0 #<- Change this to the internal network
broadcast 192.168.2.255 #<- Change this to the internal IP address of your Windows VM
gateway 192.168.2.1 #<- Change this to your gateway
bridge_ports eth0
bridge_stp off
bridge_maxwait 5
```

You will then need to make sure that your networking in Windows is configured to static, and then you will need to Configure Windows Firewall to allow the connnections through to it, as well as configure your router for forward the ports you need forwarded to the VM

Good luck